# Passing control to button in vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have a sub routine (named WBR) in "WBR45" sheet, and I have created a button in "Main" sheet. I have assigned macro also to that button.

And i have added the below code in the module1 where my sub WBR is present:

```
Sub Button2_Click()
WBR
End Sub
```

My Sub which i want to run through the button (in module1):

```
Sub WBR()

Dim Count1Criteria As Variant
Dim Count3Criteria As Variant
Dim test As Variant
Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
End Sub
```

(PS: the code is too huge so i have just given the beginning)

But I when I click on the button, it doesnt run or show any result.

Comment: Your code doesn't actually do anything which is why you don't see any effect.

Comment: in tab "Development" click "Design Mode" button and then click your button named "WBR": is it getting selected with visible handles to stretch it?

Comment: Yes I'm getting that

Answer (score 2):

I suspect your code is not connected to the code you think is under `Sub Button2_Click`, try the code below to "debug" (when pressing your button)

```
Sub Button2_Click()

MsgBox "Test here" ' <-- to test if you are getting here     
Sheets("WBR45").WBR

End Sub
```

Comment: Tried..not working...still no result..TO be clear..I have a worksheet with 5 sheets...The button is placed in "Main" sheet. The code is in "module 1"

Comment: You mean workbook with 6 sheets, right ? And you WBR sub is in a regular module? Not a worksheet ? Can I share it ?

Comment: thanks, what type of button are you using ? Acitve_x or User_Form ?

Comment: I think it's related to the type of button you are using, try edited code abode and let me know if you get the `MsgBox` ?

Comment: Nothing happened when I tried the above code. And for the type of button, I just went into "Developer" option and inserted the button.

Comment: But you didn't enter the code correctly, what is the name of your button ?

Comment: Button 2 is the name of the button

Comment: @walterwhile take out the space in "Button 2", ie change to "Button2"

Comment: You mean in the button name?

Comment: I tried all the above methods..nothing seems to work..i'm making some silly mistake..can someone please download the sample file and check what's wrong?

Comment: @Walterwhile Yep, change the button name.  You can do this by highlighting the button and changing the name in the "name box" (left of formula bar).  At the moment your code is waiting for you to push "Button2".  You have "Button 2".  This is not the same thing.

Comment: Did that still no change :(

Comment: I have attached two screenshots please take a look at it: [link](https://ufile.io/76bcf) ; [link](https://ufile.io/62c99)

Comment: just add a new button, see that it's active_x type when you do. see what it's name, and then when you double click it, you are suppose to get the VB editor screen, where you can add you code

Comment: Copy the entire Sub code of WBR into the button? @Shai Rado

Answer (score 0):

You must insert the code on the WBR subroutine example:

```
Sub WBR()
'do something
End Sub
```

The macro on the button should look something like this

```
Sub Button2_Click()
WBR
End Sub
```

Comment: I have posted the same thing above and it doesn't work

Comment: put both of the sub in the same module

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your macro isn't assigned to the button, the code you post looks correct. Right click the button > Assign macro. Then select the correct macro.

If you want to debug, place a red dot on the grey bar directly left to the code, this will insert a pause when the macro is executed.

(The code in the TS actually doesn't do anything, so it might be that the code does get executed but you don't notice anything)